# how to retrive reponse of volly responserListner outside the volly class

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am having a project for my university. My android app needs to communicate with a server to sent a command and receive some data. I am able to sent and receive data. Problem is when i want to print that data out side the volly class there is no received data available.

```
final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_url += "/?data="+ enteredUsername.getText().toString()+","+ enteredPassword.getText().toString()+","+enteredSiteId.getText().toString(),

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    returnFromServer =response.toString();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                commandStatus.setText("SERVER DOWN");
                error.printStackTrace();
                requestQueue.stop();
                }
            });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        commandStatus.setText(returnFromServer);//there is no value here out side the volly class
    }
```

**I have to compare the returned value form server for further uses.**

Answer (score 1):

Create a ResponseListener object in your class like this:

```
Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>(){
    @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                returnFromServer =response.toString();
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
};
```

and then pass the listener to volley:

```
public void yourMethod(){
    ....
    callApi(response)
    ....
}

public void callAPI(Response.Listener<String> response) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_url += "/?data="+ enteredUsername.getText().toString()+","+ enteredPassword.getText().toString()+","+enteredSiteId.getText().toString(), 
        response, 
        new Response.ErrorListener(){...} 
}
```

**Implement**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                returnFromServer =response.toString();
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
        };

    private void callAPI(Response.Listener<String> respone) {
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_url += "/?data="+ enteredUsername.getText().toString()+","+ enteredPassword.getText().toString()+","+enteredSiteId.getText().toString(),
       response,
    , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            commandStatus.setText("SERVER DOWN");
            error.printStackTrace();
            requestQueue.stop();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        commandStatus.setText(returnFromServer);//there is no value here out side the volly class
        }
    }
}
```

just call the callAPI method everywhere you want, and pass response as a parameter. if the response received from the server, onResponse method in MainActivity called.

2. another simple way in implemented  Response.Listener in the same class you call API and set response parameter in the volley to `this`.

Comment: @Md.SojibAhmed I update my answer, but if you want more implementation first look at interface design pattern in java to understanding how interfaces and callbacks work.